# Is it possible to call a java command line "app" from google script

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am exploring google script, in particular in google sheet. I want to call a client library written in java and provided as a linux shell tool.

The library is typically called within a shell script such as so:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec java cmdlib.jar
```

(there are also class path included but i am ommitting it here)

can such a jar be hosted along side google scripts and called from within google scripts

thank you,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

This is **not possible** via Google App Scripts

You could perhaps look into developing a chrome extension that connect to a Java Applet in some way and interacts with your Google Sheets.